# How to split a column containing list of lists into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

Let's suppose I have a column contain a list of lists like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"X": {0: "[['ClinicalTrials.gov Identifier: NCT05105893'], ['Recruitment Status : Completed  First Posted : November 3, 2021  Last Update Posted : November 3, 2021']]"}})
df

     X
0   [['ClinicalTrials.gov Identifier: NCT05105893'...
```

I want to split this "X" column to multiple columns with random column names like this:

```
X       rand1    rand2    rand3    rand4
[['ClinicalTrials.gov Identifier: NCT05105893'...    ClinicalTrials.gov Identifier: NCT05105893    Recruitment Status : Completed    First Posted : November 3, 2021    Last Update Posted : November 3, 2021
```

Please note that the sublists could vary for other records. In my mind, I thought of converting the sublists into columns first, and then tackling each column (sublist) individually.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Feels like it would be easier to do before creating a dataframe. How are you getting the data and how does it loook like.

Comment: The data is scraped from a webpage using pd.read_html(). Doing so gives the dataset in such a format. I understand your point though.

Comment: Is the number of column fixed? if X has fixed length of sublist, it would be easier.

Comment: Let's say X is fixed. In this case, we have two sublists. How would you do it, please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ast.literal_eval()` to convert the string to a value of its type (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "X": {
             0: "[['ClinicalTrials.gov Identifier: NCT05105893'], ['Recruitment Status : Completed  First Posted : November 3, 2021  Last Update Posted : November 3, 2021']]"
         }
     }
)

rand1 = []
rand2 = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    l = ast.literal_eval(row['X'])
    rand1.append(l[0])
    rand2.append(l[1])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'rand1': rand1,
        'rand2': rand2,
    }
)

print(new_df)  # This will print what you want

#                                          rand1                                              rand2
#0  [ClinicalTrials.gov Identifier: NCT05105893]  [Recruitment Status : Completed  First Posted ...
```

In this example, I just splited the value to two list. Now, you can easily modifty this code to split rand2 again since it is already a list type value (I didn't because it was unclear how to split the rand2).